# linking the CoreContract and the ERC20 token contract

Tags: tokens, erc-20, contract-deployment, inheritance

What is the standard way of making the link between our CoreContract and the ERC20Token contract used by the Core Contract? Are people used to use inheritance like: `MyCoreContract is MyERC20Contract { ... }` or do they deploy an instance of the ERC20 token within the core contract like: `MyCoreContract { var ERC20token = new(MyERC20token) }` . Or maybe another alternative is better ?

Best Regards

Comment: The answer to you question depends on your purpose, and more generally, on your system architecture.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inheritance does not link contracts together.  It produces single contract that has logic from both, base and inherited contracts.  For actual linking, there are several common ways:

### First way: hardcoded addresses

```solidity
contract A {
  ...
}

contract B {
  A a = A (/* address of deployed contract A here */);
}
```

This way is the cheapest in terms of gas, but does not allow using the same bytecode of contract `B` in different networks, say in devnet, testnet, and mainnet.

### Second way: constructor parameter

```solidity
contract A {
  ...
}

contract B {
  A a;

  constructor (A _a) public {
    a = _a;
  }
}
```

### Third way: deploy in constructor

This way bi-directional link may easily be established.

```solidity
contract A {
  B b;

  constructor () public {
    b = B (msg.sender);
  }
}

contract B {
  A a;

  constructor () public {
    a = new A ();
  }
}
```

### Fourth way: service registry

This way allows deploying smart contracts in any order and even modifying link after deployment.

```
contract A {
  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

  constructor (ServiceRegistry _serviceRegistry) public {
    serviceRegistry = _serviceRegistry;
    serviceRegistry.register ("A", address (this));
  }

  function getB () internal view returns (B) {
    return B (serviceRegistry.get ("B"));
  }
}

contract B {
  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

  constructor (ServiceRegistry _serviceRegistry) public {
    serviceRegistry = _serviceRegistry;
    serviceRegistry.register ("B", address (this));
  }

  function getA () internal view returns (A) {
    return A (serviceRegistry.get ("A"));
  }
}
```

etc.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply! I think inheritance will be the best option for my use case. As you said it will produce a single contract but as long as the ERC20 interface is available I don't see any drawbacks using inheritance and not having two separate contracts. Best regards

Comment: Whether there will be any drawback or not depends on what your core contract does.